# Problems with filling a path that includes decorations in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I want to construct a rectangle with two sides having a slight curvature and the other two sides being zigzag lines. In the end, I want to fill it. While the construction of the path worked the way I expected, the filling did not. How can I tell TikZ to fill the area inside this rectangle?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, decorations}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (8,0);
\coordinate (C) at (8,2);
\coordinate (D) at (0,2);

\begin{scope}[decoration=zigzag]
\def\mypath{ (A)  to[out=10,in=170] (B)
decorate[decoration=zigzag] {(B)-- (C)}  (C) to[out=170,in=10] (D)
decorate[decoration=zigzag]{(D)--(A)}
  };
  \draw [fill=red] \mypath;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 13):

You are breaking the path into pieces by repeating the coordinate names `(B)` and `(D)` hence each piece is filled individually. Removing them inside the braces (and the extra `(C)`) fixes the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (2,0);
\coordinate (C) at (2,2);
\coordinate (D) at (0,2);
\begin{scope}[decoration=zigzag]
  \draw[fill=red] (A) to[out=10,in=170] (B) 
                decorate {-- (C)}  
                to[out=170,in=10] (D) 
                decorate {--(A)};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a note: since the default decoration for the scope is already set with `\begin{scope}[decoration=zigzag]` you can remove `[decoration=zigzag]` from the path to clean it up a bit.